# How to wait for setState to be done then execute code in React native?

Tags: react-native

How to wait for setState to be done then execute code in React native ? i have an `if else` bloc that i want to execute only after the setState finishes. My code :

```js
setModalVisible(false);
if (modalVisible === false) {
   dispatch(updateUser(r.data));
} else {
   NavigationHelper.navigate('Login');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` to achieve your goal. You can keep track of state changes and execute code when the state changes.

Example:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (value) {
    // trigger when value becomes true
  } else {
    // trigger when value becomes false
  }
}, [value])

return (
  <button onClick={() => setValue(true)}>Set to true</button>
)
```